# Using of AdditionalBound in cast expressions

Tags: java, casting, java-8

Can the `AdditionalBound` described in JLS8 [cast expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) be used for casting anything **except** that a lambda expression or a method reference?

It is said, that it could be:

```
( ReferenceType {AdditionalBound} ) UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

and that:

> The target type for the casting context (§5.5) introduced by the cast
>   expression is (...) the intersection type denoted by the ReferenceType
>   and AdditionalBound terms appearing in the cast operator.

But I'm failed to find a workable example with a **non**-lambda or a **non**-method-reference example, say something like:

```
 X x = (I1&I2) some_UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
```

**UPD:**

In particular, it allows something like

`X x = (I1&I2) ~ UnaryExpression`, where `~` is unary operator.

I have no idea what `X`, `I1`, `I2` and `UnaryExpression` should be in this case.

**UPD-2:** Thanks to @Jimmy T., he has shown the workable example of

`Object x = (Number&Serializable)~0;`.

But it would be nice to see a non-redundant example, where such casting has sense.

**UPD-3:** According to the fact that all these expressions above are compiled, but all of them don't have any sense:

```
    Object l1 = (Collection & Iterable) new ArrayList<>();
    List l2 = (ByteList & Iterable) new ArrayList<>();
    Collection l3 = (List & Iterable) new ArrayList<>();
```

I can't imagine a case where such casting would be sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be compiled:

```
Object x = (Number&Serializable)~0;
```

This also can be compiled:

```
void method()
{
    method2((Number&Serializable)~0);
}

<T extends Number&Serializable> void method2(T x)
{

}
```

An example where the cast is actually needed:

```
void method(Object o)
{
  method2((List&AutoCloseable)o);
}

<T extends List&AutoCloseable> void method2(T v)
{

}
```

Comment: Cool, +1.  But this class casting case is redundant, any ideas where it would have sense?

Comment: The casting makes more sense when calling a method.

Comment: It only makes sense if you don't use a unary operator because otherwise the type of some_UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus is a primitive which is represented by a final wrapper class.

Comment: Not quite so, an example `Collection l3 = (List & Iterable) new ArrayList<>();`, but it also is senseless

Comment: It makes sense if you use it in a method call (I've added an example)

Comment: Bingo! This is the case!

Comment: @Jimmy T.: I don't get it. In what sense is `~0` different from, say, `0xffffffff` or `(-1)`? They all are compile-time constants, just like `0` or `1`, and they all behave the same, the type cast works, but is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Holger It's only an example of something workable/compilable, not something that makes sense. You can replace 0 with a variable, then it makes a little bit more sense.

Comment: Do I see it right that this only works if used with a class wich actually implements `List` and `AutoCloseable`?

Answer (score -1):

```
interface A { String msgA = "A interface"; }
interface B { String msgB = "B interface"; }
interface C { String msgC = "C interface"; }
interface ABC extends A,B,C {}

public class MultipleBounds_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ABC abc = new ABC(){};
       var ab  = (A & B) abc; 

       System.out.println( ab.msgA );
       System.out.println( ab.msgB );
       //System.out.println( ab.msgC );  //error, cannot find symbol: msgC
    }
}
```